# class variable functions

Tags: php, callable

Say `$this->varname` is equal to a string for which `is_callable()` returns true. To call it I'd have to do `$temp = $this->varname; $temp();` or...  is there another way I could call it without having to create two lines?

The problem with doing just `$temp = $this->varname()` is that that'll try to call a method within the class called varname() - it won't call the function at $this->varname.

Thanks!

Comment: [`call_user_func()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do so or use `call_user_func(_array)`. Or as Anthony has suggested to me on the internals (http://www.mail-archive.com/internals@lists.php.net/msg64647.html) you can do `${'_'.!$_=$this->varname}();`.

There already exists a pull request for PHP which is being discussed on the internals: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/301 (and a rfc https://wiki.php.net/rfc/fcallfcall)

Answer (score 1):

The other option is [`call_user_func`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php):

```
call_user_func($this->varname);
```