# $this->{$this->varname}() syntax

Tags: php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php#24931

That function does something like `$this->{$this->varname}()`. I tried it out and confirmed that that's valid syntax but it leaves me wondering...  where does php.net discuss the use of curly brackets in variable names like that?

Answer (score 1):

[Variable variables](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php):

> Class properties may also be accessed using variable property names. ...
>
> Curly braces may also be used, to clearly delimit the property name.

See examples on that page, too.

Comment: Seems like {$this->varname}() ought to work then as well..

Comment: `$s = (object)["varname" => "time"]; var_dump({$s->varname}());` this does not work. (results in parse error)

Comment: Why would you expect that to work? The braces aren't _within_ a variable expression there.

Comment: Doesn't mean that disambiguation wouldn't be useful and that, it seems to me, is the main point of the {'s in the first place. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15888945/class-variable-functions is an example of where it'd be useful. Call `{$this->varname}();` instead of `call_user_func('...')`.

Comment: Sure, I'm not arguing that it wouldn't be useful, just that it hasn't been designed to work that way. I'm guessing that the parser encounters a `{` that's not part of an unfinished expression and treats it like a regular block of code, like with `if () { ... }`.

Answer (score 1):

Why shouldn't it work?

These are variable variables/function names.

```
$f = "time";
$f(); // returns the actual time
```

It's now the same, only in object context (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php):

```
$object->$f; // calls the method with the name $f in $object
```

Now, to say that it is the method with the name `$this->varname`, you need to write `$this->{$this->varname}` as `$this->$this->varname` will be interpreted as `($this->$this)->varname` which results `in $this->{$this->__toString()}->varname` what you don't want.